# Xamarin.UWP UnhandledException Event Handler Never Gets Fired

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, unhandled-exception, xamarin.uwp

In my App.xaml.cs ctor, I hooked up `UnhandledException`

```
this.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
```

, then I provided handler to send error info to GoogleAnalytics

```
private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var unhandledException = e.Exception;
    AnalyticsManager.LogError("", e.Exception.Message, "UnhandledException");
}
```

I intentionally introduce `DevideByZeroException` in my code that is never handled and I would expect my `OnUnhandledException` handler to be called but that does not happen, regardless of Debug or Release mode. I put a break point in this handler and that break point is never reached.

Doing same on Xamarin.Android on the other hand will reach the breakpoint.

**UPDATE**

It seem to be working only once app is loaded and an unhandled error occurs. So, in both cases (hooking up UnhandledException in c-tor or in onLaunched) will work if error occurs after app has been loaded, i.e. on button click. Otherwise, i.e. unhandled exception occurs during the load of app, the event handler is never hit in Xamarin.UWP.
Interestingly, on Xamarin.Android, the handler will be hit always.

Answer (score 1):

> I intentionally introduce DevideByZeroException in my code that is never handled and I would expect my OnUnhandledException handler to be called but that does not happen, regardless of Debug or Release mode.

`OnUnhandledException` handler will not be called when I placed `DevideByZeroException` in the App's constructor. If I place it in the `OnLaunched` method, it will be called as expected, as well as putting in the MainPage's constructor.

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application#Events), this event will only fire when there is no longer any possibility that app code can catch an exception.

> Note that this event will only fire when there is no longer any possibility that app code can catch an exception. For example, imagine that an app event handler calls a Windows Runtime API that in turn invokes a callback. If the inner app code throws an exception and does not catch it, the exception will propagate through the Windows Runtime back to the outer layer of app code, which is given a chance to catch it. The UnhandledException event is fired only when there are no more opportunities for app code to catch an exception through normal propagation.

In order to catch the exception directly, you could use `try-catch` technique. For more you could refer to [**Exception handling for Windows Runtime apps in C# or Visual Basic**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/dn532194(v=win.10)).

Comment: Thanks Nico, I am using try.. catch but there is always a possibility of unhandled exceptions, so having UnhandledException Event is to deal with that and help discover them.  I am aware it does only fire if all other chances to handle it are exhausted